# Unable to add dependency in my Pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to creating pod for my library. My library use some third party library like Alamofire, Socket.IO-Client-Swift, AlamofireImage, etc. I have to add them as dependencies in my `AppName.podspec`.

See snapshot to preview `AppName.podspec`:

[image]

There is no error. but when I install the pod using `pod install`, none of the third party libraries install.

Is there any other way to add a dependency to my pod file? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please do not put screenshot of your pod spec, post its text. Else, All your dependencies are commented (starting with a #).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that lines that include the dependancies are commented out (in ruby a comment is created with a hash: #)

You need to remove the hash and then it should work.